# Add to cart bookable product by URL - WooCommerce Bookings

Tags: wordpress, get, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I'm using `Woocommerce Bookings`

How to add to cart bookable product by URL?

```
/?add-to-cart=[n.product]
```

How can I pass an avaiable date with variations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem recently but I discovered a solution.

It's not possible to add a bookable product just by adding the right variables to the end of the URL because WooCommerce Bookings expects data to be sent via the `POST` method as you can see at the plugin's source:

```
// woocommerce-bookings/includes/class-wc-booking-cart-manager.php : ln 256
$booking_form                       = new WC_Booking_Form( $product );
$cart_item_meta['booking']          = $booking_form->get_posted_data( $_POST );
$cart_item_meta['booking']['_cost'] = $booking_form->calculate_booking_cost( $_POST );

// Create the new booking
$new_booking = $this->create_booking_from_cart_data( $cart_item_meta, $product_id );
```

and:

```
// woocommerce-bookings/includes/class-wc-booking-cart-manager.php : ln 276
private function create_booking_from_cart_data( $cart_item_meta, $product_id, $status = 'in-cart' ) {
    // Create the new booking
    $new_booking_data = array(
        'product_id'    => $product_id, // Booking ID
        'cost'          => $cart_item_meta['booking']['_cost'], // Cost of this booking
        'start_date'    => $cart_item_meta['booking']['_start_date'],
        'end_date'      => $cart_item_meta['booking']['_end_date'],
        'all_day'       => $cart_item_meta['booking']['_all_day'],
    );
```

Instead of this:

```
<a href="/?add-to-cart=product_id">Add to cart</a>
```

You need to create a form with a number of hidden fields with the 'Add to cart' button/link as the submit button.

Something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="product_id">
    <input type="hidden" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_year" value="booking_start_date_year">
    <input type="hidden" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_month" value="booking_start_date_month">
    <input type="hidden" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_day" value="booking_start_date_day">
    <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
</form>
```